# Unable to open files, with the path in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, python-3.7

I have reinstalled the anaconda after formatting my machine, since I am getting error while opening the files in jupyter notebook.

Initially I tried access the file from desktop location, as I got an error again tried to access from D drive. both were not successful attempts.

```
salaries = pd.read_excel('D:\\housesales.xlsx')
```

Below is the error

> FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) `<ipython-input-13-6d8e17cbb085>` in `<module>` ----> 1 salaries = pd.read_excel('D:\housesales.xlsx') ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs) 186 else: 187 kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value --> 188 return func(*args, **kwargs) 189 return wrapper 190 return _deprecate_kwarg ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs) 186 else: 187 kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value --> 188 return func(*args, **kwargs) 189 return wrapper 190 return _deprecate_kwarg ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, parse_cols, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skip_footer, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds) 348 349 if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile): --> 350 io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine) 351 352 return io.parse( ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in **init**(self, io, engine) 651 self._io = _stringify_path(io) 652 --> 653 self._reader = self._enginesengine 654 655 def **fspath**(self): ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in **init**(self, filepath_or_buffer) 422 self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data) 423 elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, compat.string_types): --> 424 self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer) 425 else: 426 raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in' ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows) 109 else: 110 filename = os.path.expanduser(filename) --> 111 with open(filename, "rb") as f: 112 peek = f.read(peeksz) 113 if peek == b"PK\x03\x04": # a ZIP file FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\housesales.xlsx'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like your `housesales.xlsx` file is on your Desktop, but you do not include the `Desktop` folder in the path to your file.

```
salaries = pd.read_excel('D:\\Desktop\housesales.xlsx')
```

I recommend you use jupyter lab as it has a file tree.

Running this bash command in a notebook cell will tell you the working directory of your jupyter instance so you know where it is looking for files.

```
!pwd
```

You could also move your file to that directory and then just access it as

```
salaries = pd.read_excel('housesales.xlsx')
```